# ExecuteSqlCommand return -1?

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I am trying to call a stored procedure from code , in ef core 2 i found that i can use **context.database.ExecuteSqlCommand()** function to execute any stored procedure in my database.

While the stored procedure works fine in my sql server instance :

[image]
calling it from my code , returns -1 result !?:

```
  using (var context = new AZPDBDEMOGZContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {

            var existUser = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GetIdUsager_ByNomPrenomEmail @p0,@p1,@p2", parameters:new[] { "rouarouarouarouaroua", "wiem", "test@gmail.com" });

        }
```

what m i doping wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteSqlCommand will only return a 'rows affected' integer for a DML query aka insert/update/delete. Your stored proc looks like its returning a result set so it returns -1 as you've not provided a statement that changes the data source. You'll need to create a POCO and use FromSql to populate it.